# Simple Image Slider in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, slider

I want to create a simple image slider using JavaScript.
The slider should have a back and previous arrow for changing images plus a label at below showing current slide active.

I don't want to use any JS framework and because its for mobile website so i want it to be as optimized as possible.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ok. Where are you having problems, or are you just asking someone to do the work for you?

Comment: @hk99 what have you done so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is help you http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/imageSlideShow.htm